# I need a more efficient way of checking if multiple $_POST parameters isset

Tags: php

I have these variables, and I need to check if all of them isset(). I feel there *has* to be a more efficient way of checking them rather than one at a time.

```
$jdmMethod = $_POST['jdmMethod'];
$cmdMethod = $_POST['cmdMethod'];
$vbsMethod = $_POST['vbsMethod'];
$blankPage = $_POST['blankPage'];
$facebook = $_POST['facebook'];
$tinychat = $_POST['tinychat'];
$runescape = $_POST['runescape'];
$fileUrl = escapeshellcmd($_POST['fileUrl']);
$redirectUrl = escapeshellcmd($_POST['redirectUrl']);
$fileName = escapeshellcmd($_POST['fileName']);
$appData = $_POST['appData'];
$tempData = $_POST['tempData'];
$userProfile = $_POST['userProfile'];
$userName = $_POST['userName'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
     $allOk = true;
     $checkVars = array('param', 'param2', …);
     foreach($checkVars as $checkVar) {
          if(!isset($_POST[$checkVar]) OR !$_POST[$checkVar]) {
               $allOk = false;
               // break; // if you wish to break the loop
          }
     }

     if(!$allOk) {
         // error handling here
     }
```

Comment: Don't use Exceptions for non-exceptional cases.

Comment: `OR` is easier to type than `||` on a german (mac) keyboard layout ;) Let me guess your next question: »Who uses macs?« ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$jdmMethod = isset($_POST['jdmMethod']) ? $_POST['jdmMethod'] : NULL;
```

It's [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: Better yet, make a function that does that: `function get_or_else($array, $key, $default=null){ return isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : $default; }`

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  You could make a list of expected fields:

```
$expected = array(
 'jdmMethod',
 'cmdMethod',
 'fileName'
); // etc...
```

... then loop those and make sure all the keys are in place.

```
$valid = true;
foreach ($expected as $ex) {
 if (!array_key_exists($ex, $_POST)) {
   $valid  = false;
   break;
 }
 $_POST[$ex] = sanitize($_POST[$ex]);
}

if (!$valid) {
  // handle the problem
}
```

If you can develop a generic sanitize function, that will help - you can just sanitize each as you loop.

Another thing I like to use is function that gives a default as it sanitizes.

```
function checkParam($key = false, $default = null, $type = false) {
    if ($key === false)
        return $default;

    $found_option = null;           
    if (array_key_exists($key,$_REQUEST))
        $found_option = $_REQUEST[$key];
    if (is_null($found_option))
        $found_option = $default;       
    if ($type !== false) {
        if ($type == 'string' && !is_string($found_option))
            return $default;
        if ($type == 'numeric' && !is_numeric($found_option))
            return $default;
        if ($type == 'object' && !is_object($found_option))
            return $default;
        if ($type == 'array' && !is_array($found_option))
            return $default;
    }
    return sanitize($found_option);
}
```

When a default is possible, you'd not want to do a loop, but rather check for each independently:

```
$facebook = checkParam('facebook', 'no-facebook', 'string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a function like this:

```
// $k is the key
// $d is a default value if it's not set
// $filter is a call back function name for filtering
function check_post($k, $d = false, $filter = false){
    $v = array_key_exists($_POST[$k]) ? $_POST[$k] : $d;
    return $filter !== false ? call_user_func($filter,$v) : $v;
}

$keys = array("jdmMethod", array("fileUrl", "escapeshellcmd"));
$values = array();
foreach($keys as $k){
    if(is_array($k)){
        $values[$k[0]] = check_post($k[0],false,$k[1]);
    }else{
        $values[$k] = check_post($k[0]);
    }
}
```

You could extend the keys array to contain a different default value for each post-value if you wish.

EDIT:

If you want to make sure all of these have a non-default value you could do something like:

```
if(sizeof(array_filter($values)) == sizeof($keys)){
    // Not all of the values are set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work (not tested, from memory)

```
function handleEmpty($a, $b) {
   if ($b === null) {
       return false;
   } else {
      return true;
}

array_reduce($_POST, "handleEmpty");
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not the answer you are looking for, but no.

You can create an array an loop through that array to check for a value, but it doesn't get any better than that.

Example:

```
$postValues = array("appData","tempData",... etc);
foreach($postedValues as $postedValue){
   if(isset($_POST[$postedValue])){
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: 1) You can use `foreach` here. 2) How are you going to set variables? 3) no any checks in this code, result of isset is unused.

Comment: yeah, its been a while that I coded PHP, so I corrected it, thnx :)
changed it.

Comment: If I may - if you aren't a PHP person, it doesn't make a lot of sense to be on here answering PHP questions.  I, for one, would never presume to answer an ASP question because odds are, I'd be wrong.  Something to think about, anyway.

Comment: downgrading my answer, while its correct, ... Im mostley programming c# but I still write some PHP now an than, I just blacked out about the foreach.. damn man :S