# Using $_POST += array() for default values

Tags: php, arrays, post

I'm finishing up a small contact form and had a question about providing default values for `$_POST`. The reason I'm asking about default values is because within my form I have fields like this:

```
<input type="text" name="fullname" value="<?php echo $_POST['fullname']; ?>" />
```

Clearly I would like to retain the submitted value if I do not permit the data to clear. This raises errors when the page is first loaded, since there is no value for `$_POST['fullname']`.

To my question: is there anything I should be concerend about providing default values to the `$_POST` array like I'm doing in the next code-sample:

```
$_POST += array(
  'fullname' = '',
);
```

If `$_POST['fullname']` already exists, it will be retained - if it doesn't, it will be created within the array. This way, upon loading the form, blank values will be presented in the input fields.

*Don't worry, all

I sanitize my data

Thank you for the help*

Comment: `<?php echo $_POST['fullname']; ?>` doesn't look like sanitizing your data.

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256512/i-need-a-more-efficient-way-of-checking-if-multiple-post-parameters-isset/6256555#6256555

Comment: @icktoofay The code for cleaning up the data isn't provided. It's done against `$_POST` earlier in execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you are doing so, put that data in your container, do not modify superglobals. Create class that'll contain your data - then you'll have the interface do sanitize, manipulate and get it te proper way. Import data from $_POST and then validate, if all necessary values are in.

As for code:

```
<?php
class PostData
    {
    private $data;

    public function __construct(array $data)
        {
        $this->data = is_array($data)
            ? $data
            : array();
        }

    public function set($key, $value)
        {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
        }

    public function get($key, $default, $escaping)
        {
        if(isset($this->data[$key]))
            {
            switch($escaping)
                {
                case 'htmlspecialchars':
                    {
                    return htmlspecialchars($this->data[$key]);
                    break;
                    }
                case 'mysql_real_escape_string':
                    {
                    return mysql_real_escape_string($this->data[$key]);
                    break;
                    }
                // and so on, your invention goes here
                default:
                    {
                    return $this->data[$key];
                    }
                }
            }
        else
            {
            return $default;
            }
        }
    }

$postData = new PostData($_POST);
```

Comment: Totally agree. It's better practice to always assume $_POST data contains untrusted data, and to copy it from there into another location that means "this data is clean."

Comment: So you're saying I should create a form class, pass in `$_POST` to the constructor, clean it up internally and then get values out via something like `$Form->getValue('fullname')` where the result is determined internally?

Comment: @Aristotle, something like that, yes. It could look like `$f = new FormData($_POST); $f->sanitize(array('first_name'=>'string')); echo $f['first_name'];` (assuming the class implements `ArrayAccess`).

Comment: That is the implementation detail - but sure, you can do it that way. You can also create class PostData, import $_POST inside it and pass the object to the Form class. That way you'll satisfy the Dependency Injection requirements, which will be also nice.

Comment: @Tomasz I think I understand what you mean. Could you provide just a bit of pseudo-code in your answer to give me some more direction? I appreciate the help.

Comment: A bit more effort than I had expected, but thank you for the investment of time. If you don't mind me asking, what is the reason for casting the `$data` passed into the constructor to an array?

Comment: Also, since the switch statement returns in each case, is it necessary to break? If I'm not mistaken, the breaks will never be met.

Comment: "Our customer is king", they say. ;] For the "array $data" part - this is not casting, this is PHP 5.3 type hinting requiring passed variable to be array, error otherwise. OTOH you have shorthand if validation in ctor, use one of them [either simplify ctor body or remove "array" from argument list.

Comment: For the breaks - this is my "programmer's habit" to include them in every switch case. You may remove them and it'll work perfectly, but for the consistency I'll always keep them.

Comment: I don't like this code. 1) $escaping should contain string? Then create constants in this class, which will contain names of allowed functions, to avoid typing name of function each time. Also, without constants we have to look into this code to remember, which functions are supported. 2) If for escaping function you will need arguments, what will you do? New argument for `get` method? It's better to use escaping in normal way, without passing name of function. 3) Wrong indents for braces (I like this style of braces, but indents are placed wrong).

Comment: 1) +1 to this, but as I've said - this is implementation detail, you can use, you can change. 2) I'll add fourth argument - array with params. But it is not the case - this was to shw the idea of many output escapers you can use. For 1-minute hacked code it's not bad at all. If I were to use this in production, I'll use decorator or other OO pattern. 3) This definitely is not wrong - it's Whitesmith's style: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Whitesmiths_style . I use it.

Comment: Then sorry about criticism of braces.

Comment: No problem, I know how religious can one be when it comes to coding styles. ;]

Answer (score 2):

Create function:

```
function displayValue($field) {
  if(isset($_POST[$field])) {
    echo 'value="' . htmlentities($_POST[$field]) . '"';
  }
}
```

And then use like:

```
<input type="text" name="fullname" <?php displayValue('fullname'); ?> />
```

Comment: best way to do it IMHO, altho I would use the ternary operator to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
<?php echo empty($_POST['fullname']) ? null : $_POST['fullname']; ?>
```

Comment: Too verbose. I may have a dozen or so inputs on the page.